# proper one-sided test for truncated distribution

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, p-value, truncation

I have positional segments that contain N number of mutations. Each mutation has a frequency which is determined by taking the number of reads supporting the alternate allele (r) and dividing them by the total number of reads at that position (n). Therefore each segment contains a distribution of frequencies (r/n; 0< r/n <1). I need to determine if a new observed frequency (xo) is significantly less than the mean of the frequency distribution of a specific segment. What would be the best approach?

I was considering calculating mean and standard deviation, and calculate a Z score and thereby calculate the p-value for the xo observation. But it is naive that it does not consider the number of reads (n) (unlike a binomial test). Also, we consider a position as mutation only when (0

Is there a better test to be using that might take all of this into account when determining significance?

Comment: How large are the counts, typically?

Comment: The counts can be as low as 10 or as high as 10000. Typicially around 30 to 50